# Start a postgres server with pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, debian, pgadmin

I'm trying to start a postgreSQL server in Debian 10 in order to access this database: https://catalogofraneitalia.wordpress.com/database/.
I have never used postgreSQL before and I have tried to follow the instructions I found on the internet. This is what I have run up to now:

- `sudo apt -y install gnupg2`
- `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
- `` echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" |sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list ``
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt -y install postgresql-11`
- `sudo apt install postgis postgresql-11-postgis-3`
- I checked that postgreSQL is active, enabled and accepting connections
- `sudo su - postgres`, `psql` and `create user username with superuser password 'password'`  with the username and password chosen
- `sudo apt install pgadmin3 pgadmin3-data`
- I opened pgadmin and I cliked on Add server, inserting the username and password previously created and I received the message `Peer authentication failed for user "username"`

Answer (score 1):

the correct steps to install pg are in the official site: https://www.postgresql.org/download/

Follow the steps on screen, once initialized you can open the port (listen_address and pg_hba.conf), restart the service, and done... you can connect from other machine.

Other thing, pgadmin3 is deprecated, try using pgadmin4.